# How to show specific TextBoxes from a Grid and hide all the other textboxes?

Tags: c#, wpf

I am current working on a C# WPF application. I have a grid with almost 10 TextBoxes[TextBoxes in a GRID](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IywHc.png) , Based on the customer requirement I have to show him the textboxes. I am current reading a variable from a file lets suppose 4 and show him the 4 text boxes out of 10 or if i write 5 in textfile my code should show him 5 text boxes out of 10. 
How can I achieve such phenomena in my code

Comment: You could make a list of your `textboxes` (in order). Then, with two simple `for loops` : `for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) textboxes[i].Visible = true;`, and `for (int i = n; i < 10; i++) textboxes[i].Visible = false;`

Comment: sorry but i am a newbie how can  i make list of texboxes? can u guide

Comment: Following @RogerN answer (which is great): `var textboxes = new[] { textBox1, textBox2, ..., textBox10 };`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your textboxes all share a common parent container (i.e. a Grid) then iterating over them is pretty easy. The XAML might look something like this:

```
<Grid Name="textBoxContainer">
    <!-- row, column definitions omitted -->
    <TextBox />
    <TextBox />
    <TextBox />
    <!-- etc... -->
</Grid>
```

... and then in your code-behind file, you need to iterate over these text boxes like so:

```
int showBoxCount = 4; // this number gets loaded from your file elsewhere
foreach (var textBox in textBoxContainer.Children.OfType<TextBox>()) {
    if (showBoxCount > 0)
        textBox.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
    else
        textBox.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
    showBoxCount--;
}
```

If the text boxes do not share a common parent container then you'll need to give each of them a name and then put them into an array manually in your code-behind file.

XAML:

```
<TextBox Name="txt1" />
<TextBox Name="txt2" />
<TextBox Name="txt3" />
<!-- etc... -->
```

Code-behind:

```
var textBoxes = new TextBox[] { txt1, txt2, txt3, etc... };
int showBoxCount = 4; // this number gets loaded from your file elsewhere
foreach (var textBox in textBoxes) {
    if (showBoxCount > 0)
        textBox.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
    else
        textBox.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
    showBoxCount--;
}
```